# Horizontal Scrolling in AnyLogic

Tags: anylogic

I am new to using AnyLogic and am having teething issues getting used to having to manually scroll horizontally. Is there a way to map actions to mouse buttons? E.g. horizontal scrolling using side wheel on a mouse.

As an add-on, is it possible to use a 3D space mouse within AnyLogic?

Thanks in advance.

I have already tried looking at settings but couldn't find anything relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Just click `Shift` while scrolling with your mouse wheel and it scrolls horizontally. (This is also true for Windows in general)

> As an add-on, is it possible to use a 3D space mouse within AnyLogic?

No idea what that even is :)